# Superagent response body undefined until next line

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jestjs, superagent

I am testing my express API using Jest and Supertest. For some reason this does not work:

```
const id = await request.post('/program')
    .send(body)
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(201).body.id;
```

It fails with error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

  154 |             sessionId: defaults.authorId
  155 |         };
> 156 |         const id = await request.post('/program')
      |                           ^
  157 |             .send(body)
  158 |             .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  159 |             .expect(201).body.id;

  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/program.test.js:156:27)
```

However, just moving the `.body.id` to the next line fixes the problem.

```
const res = await request.post('/program')
    .send(body)
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(201);

const id = res.body.id;
```

Why is this happening? Is the request not being `await`ed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you are reading the attributes from the return value of `expect(201)`.

As the return value does not have a `body` attribute, it crashes when you try to read the `id` property from it.

In the second case, you are reading `body.id` from the response of your server. As you are returning an object with `id` attribute, you are able to read it.

If you want to check that your method is returning an object with an `id` property you can do so with:

```
const res = await request.post('/program')
    .send(body)
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect({ id: 201 });
```